# Uninstall JBoss Tools 4.3.0 Final (Hibernate) from Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

I installed JBoss Tools 4.3.0 Final in my Eclipse Luna which installed Hibernate tools (Indigo) 3.4.x

That's why I think it's not working the reverse engineering. I followed the steps but classes are not being created. Even if I succeeded to map the tables.

So I decided to uninstall JBoss and Hibernate tools. When I go to Help > Marketplace > Installed and then I click uninstall, this reopens my Eclipse to refresh the changes, but Hibernate is still there. How can I uninstall the JBoss Tools manually from Eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to uninstall something from eclipse you need to go Eclipse -> about eclipse -> Installation details. and uninstall everything you do not need

Comment: I have a ton of stack trace errors after uninstalling Jboss in Windows 10 from Eclipse -> about eclipse -> Installation details.  It makes Eclipse unusable.  Unfortunately, I had to reinstall Eclipse and DO NOT INSTALL JBOSS AGAIN.

Answer (score 0):

another way to reach Installation Details would be Help-> About Eclipse-> Installation Details

Comment: Question was already answered, No need to duplicate the content again.